# Why Do Vulcans Have Pets?

Tags: star-trek

On the Vulcan's home planet they have creatures known as Sehlats. As explained they are basically giant bears with 6 in. fangs. What is the logical reason for Vulcans to have these as pets? Are they like protector dogs or just pets they keep?

Comment: Given that emotions are suppressed for the Vulcan race I would assume that they are kept for some specific/practical reason. Maybe they keep the mice away or help to fertilize the gardens...

Comment: @Odin1806 - Giving a child a pet (in this case one that can bite your face off if you forget to feed it) teaches them responsibility

Comment: @Valorum - See, knew it had to be somethin...

Comment: "Pet" may simply be an easy translation for a concept which has no direct analog in English. While I do not assert that the following example is the actual case, it is plausible that the Vulcans have the concept of a kind of individual animal stewardship which combines a developmental journey for an immature Vulcan, and providing some kind of ecological benefit (e.g., temporarily removing a single predator from an ecosystem where it may destabilize a desired prey species population, or "fostering" an orphaned animal). The needs of screenwriting may make explanation too wordy, hence "pet".